# Terraform host name with empty CNAME record name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I have this cdn endpoint custom domain:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint_custom_domain" "endpointfrontend" {
  name            = "myappdev"
  cdn_endpoint_id = azurerm_cdn_endpoint.cdnendpoint.id
  host_name       = "${azurerm_dns_cname_record.cnamefrontend.name}.${data.azurerm_dns_zone.dnszone.name}"
  cdn_managed_https {
    certificate_type = "Dedicated"
    protocol_type = "ServerNameIndication"
  }
}
```

And this CNAME:

```
resource "azurerm_dns_cname_record" "cnamefrontend" {
  name                = var.cname_name
  zone_name           = data.azurerm_dns_zone.dnszone.name 
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_dns_zone.dnszone.resource_group_name
  ttl                 = 3600
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_cdn_endpoint.cdnendpoint.id
}
```

And this DNS Zone:

```
data "azurerm_dns_zone" "dnszone" { 
  name                = "myapp.app"
  resource_group_name = "rg-my"
}
```

Also I have one main.tf for the dev stage and one for the prod stage.
The host names should look like this:

```
dev.myapp.app 
myapp.app
```

Since the host name is defined by the cname.name+dnszone.name, cname.name has to be empty for myapp.app, since the dnszone.name is equal to myapp.app.
I dont know how to do this.

Comment: How are you differentiating between the environments? Are you using workspaces?

Comment: I have a pipeline with a dev and prod stage. Depending on the stage, there will be diffrent main.tf files used

Comment: Ok, and where are those values coming from? The `dev.myapp.app` and `myapp.app`?

Comment: myapp.app is the DNS Zone name. So basically for the dev stage i want host_name= ${azurerm_dns_cname_record.cnamefrontend.name}.${data.azurerm_dns_zone.dnszone.name} and on the prod stage host_name = ${data.azurerm_dns_zone.dnszone.name}. The problem is I dont know how to accomplish such conditions in tf.

Comment: So that's the reason for my first question. How will the pipeline know to which env to deploy? Is there a variable in the pipeline or in your code?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for me was a conditional expression.

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint_custom_domain" "endpointfrontend" {
  name            = "myapp${var.environment}"
  cdn_endpoint_id = azurerm_cdn_endpoint.cdnendpoint.id
  host_name       = azurerm_dns_cname_record.cnamefrontend.name == "@"? "${data.azurerm_dns_zone.dnszone.name}" :"${azurerm_dns_cname_record.cnamefrontend.name}.${data.azurerm_dns_zone.dnszone.name}"

  cdn_managed_https {
    certificate_type = "Dedicated"
    protocol_type = "ServerNameIndication"
  }
}
```